# Using Faraday Ruby gem to download image and write to disk

Tags: ruby, file, download, binary, io

When using the [Faraday](https://github.com/technoweenie/faraday) gem to hit a URL for an image like this:

```
http_conn = Faraday.new do |builder|
  builder.adapter Faraday.default_adapter
end 
response = http_conn.get 'http://example.tld/image.png'
```

How can you write the image file from the Faraday response to disk?

Debugging the `response.body` attribute shows it is binary data.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Why not just write the `response.body` like any other file?

```
File.open('image.png', 'wb') { |fp| fp.write(response.body) }
```

Comment: What happens here if the response body is large? It looks like the whole body is read into memory before its written to the file - it'd be good to be able to write to the file in chunks.

Comment: @JP. Isn't it Faraday that is slurping the whole image into memory? Or are you asking how to get Faraday to stream it?

Comment: Exactly, yeah I'm wondering if there's a way to get Faraday to stream the body. I've been looking to implement an HTTP IO class using HTTP byte ranges so I can (for example) retrieve a small file from within large zip archive without retrieving the whole thing (ruby zip can do the same with File IO objects by seeking and only reading the zip central directory and the requested content)

Comment: @JP. Maybe a Faraday-specific question would work. I haven't looked at Faraday for a couple years.